# Should element name or id be used to access form elements?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm using the jQuery validator plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/.

I have found that I can access elements in the form using either their ID or their name (at least with Firefox and Chrome).  Is one way more correct and browser compatible than the other?  Or maybe I should do something else altogether?

http://jsbin.com/daxaju/2/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $("#myForm").validate({
                    submitHandler: function(form) {
                        console.log('using id',form.myElementID.value);
                        console.log('using name',form.myElementName.value);
                    }
                });                
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="text" name="myElementName" id="myElementID" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I have one for using ID, another for using name, and a third for using both!

Answer (score 0):

Since on an `input` a name is somehow required (I don't know what the documentation says about this, but if you want to retrieve it later, for example in PHP, you should put a `name` attribute on it), I think that referencing your element by its `name` it safer.

As you can see here : http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-all-form-objects.phtml , native API use the name to reference a form element.

Comment: Thanks Cyrille,  Interestingly, if I have two inputs in my form `<input type="text" name="myElementName" id="myElementID" />` and `<input type="text" name="myElementID" id="myElementName" />`, I can't read either of them!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to put both id and name, id for jquery and name for php.
For browser compatible, id/name all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting an element by it's Id is the fastest. Id is(should be) unique on the document. It works on all the browsers.